# Folder seems to exist in OS but fails silently upon `sudo rm -rf dirname`

Tags: python, linux, directory

I am trying to delete a folder, but failing to do so. I am sudo, and have all permissions.

`cd /path/to/parent`

`ls`

```
001  003  005  007  009  011  013  015  017  019  021                 dent_detections_3d.ply      dent_spread_debug.png             paint_chip_spread_debug.png
002  004  006  008  010  012  014  016  018  020  _det__grouped.json  dent_detections_debug.json  paint_chip_detections_debug.json
```

I want to delete `003` which is the problematic folder. Other folders behave normally.

Observations:

1. `cd 003` gives `-bash: cd: 003: No such file or directory`
2. `sudo rm -rf 003` or `sudo rm -rf 003/` gives empty output, then `ls` gives the same as above (`003` exists).
3. 

```
python
> import os
> path.os.exists("path/to/parent")
>> True
> path.os.exists("path/to/parent/003")
>> False
> os.mkdir("path/to/parent/003")
>> 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
OSError: [Errno 17] File exists: '/path/to/parent/003'
```

What may be causing this? How to debug this? I want the folder removed, and I need this to not happen again.

---

EDIT to answer comments:

```
> ls -la

total 6144
drwxr-xr-x 2 noam root      0 Dec 28 13:28 .
drwxr-xr-x 2 noam root      0 Dec  9 18:41 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 noam root      0 Dec 28 13:28 001
drwxr-xr-x 2 noam root      0 Dec 28 13:28 002
drwxr-xr-x 2 noam root      0 Dec 28 13:28 003
drwxr-xr-x 2 noam root      0 Dec 28 13:26 004
drwxr-xr-x 2 noam root      0 Dec 28 13:26 005
drwxr-xr-x 2 noam root      0 Dec 28 13:26 006
drwxr-xr-x 2 noam root      0 Dec 28 13:26 007
drwxr-xr-x 2 noam root      0 Dec 28 13:26 008
drwxr-xr-x 2 noam root      0 Dec 28 13:26 009
drwxr-xr-x 2 noam root      0 Dec 28 13:26 010
drwxr-xr-x 2 noam root      0 Dec 28 13:26 011
drwxr-xr-x 2 noam root      0 Dec 28 13:26 012
drwxr-xr-x 2 noam root      0 Dec 28 13:26 013
drwxr-xr-x 2 noam root      0 Dec 28 13:26 014
drwxr-xr-x 2 noam root      0 Dec 28 13:26 015
drwxr-xr-x 2 noam root      0 Dec 28 13:26 016
drwxr-xr-x 2 noam root      0 Dec 28 13:26 017
drwxr-xr-x 2 noam root      0 Dec 28 13:26 018
drwxr-xr-x 2 noam root      0 Dec 28 13:26 019
drwxr-xr-x 2 noam root      0 Dec 28 13:26 020
drwxr-xr-x 2 noam root      0 Dec 28 13:26 021
-rwxr-xr-x 1 noam root 684753 Dec 12 11:58 _det__grouped.json
-rwxr-xr-x 1 noam root   7604 Dec 12 11:58 dent_detections_3d.ply
-rwxr-xr-x 1 noam root  89902 Dec 12 11:58 dent_detections_debug.json
-rwxr-xr-x 1 noam root 377863 Dec 12 11:58 dent_spread_debug.png
-rwxr-xr-x 1 noam root     24 Dec 12 11:58 paint_chip_detections_debug.json
-rwxr-xr-x 1 noam root 362525 Dec 12 11:58 paint_chip_spread_debug.png
```

---

EDIT2 with the information that a race-condition is the problem

Relevant code chunk that creates the folder:

```
if os.path.exists(cluster_folder_path):
    shutil.rmtree(cluster_folder_path)
os.mkdir(cluster_folder_path)
```

Comment: Which exactly operating system are you using?

Comment: can you share "ls -la" results?

Comment: What does `ls -l` show? `exists` will return `False` for certain file types, including broken symlinks.

Comment: @Slybot please see edit

Comment: @match please see edit

Comment: The timestamp on those directories implies this might be a race condition. Is something creating/modifying these while you are trying to use them? You might be better off not testing for existence, and just try/catch the creation.

Comment: `sudo rm -fr 003 && touch 003` results in `003` being a new empty file? If it does this is definitely a race condition with something that recreates `003` as a directory

Comment: @Bakuriu Yes, it makes `003` into a file. Can you explain why this did anything, and what really happened here, and why this implies a race condition?

Comment: @Gulzar It shows that the directory **is** deleted, so what you saw is just some program recreating it right away. The command I suggested deleted the `003` directory and created a file called `003` immediately after. So the directory *does* get deleted, but there is some process actively watching/notified by the kernel that recreates it immediately after. You can now move from "how to delete `003`" to "how can I find out which process is doing this and how to stop the process".

Comment: @Bakuriu Please see EDIT2. I am assuming `shutil.rmtree` creates a process that attempts to delete the folder, and having created it too soon caused the race condition. What I fail to understand is 1. Why only `003` (also happens in consecutive runs if I delete the entire `parent`)? this seems the same for all folders. 2. The Python process is long dead when probing the folder structure using bash. These make me believe my explanation is lacking. However, when I changed `if` to `while` in the code in EDIT2, the problem went away. Can you make sense of this?

Comment: `rmdir "*003*"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the code in EDIT2 to

```
while os.path.exists(cluster_folder_path):
    shutil.rmtree(cluster_folder_path)
os.mkdir(cluster_folder_path)
```

forced the folder to actually be deleted before moving on to create it, thus preventing the race condition.

I was not able to understand why this happens only for a single folder, or why this one and not others. I was also not able to understand why this kept happening after Python was already not running.

Will accept an answer that manages to explain that.